# Sequences with a defined pattern that changes if a condition is met

Tags: sequences-and-series

If we have a sequence like this one, where every term is 3 more than the previous term except in certain situations, then an extra 2 is added. How do we go about finding a general formula for these types of sequences:

2, 5, 8, *13*, 16, 19, *24*, 27, 30, *35*

If it was only +3 for all terms, we could have just used 2 + 3x but the extra condition is throwing me off. Is there a way we could incorporate that?

Comment: $a_{n+1} = a_1 + (km+r) \lfloor \frac{n}{m} \rfloor + k\{ \frac{n}{m} \}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then, if we let the $n$th term of the sequence be $a_n$, then we have the following formula:

$$a_{n+1} = 2 + 11\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \rfloor + 9\{\frac{n}{3}\}$$
where $\{x\}$ indicates the fractional part of $x$. $\hspace{1cm}\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$.

Comment: THIS IS EXACTLY WHAT I NEEDED. I SEARCHED THE INTERNET BUT COULDN'T FIND HOW TO DO THIS. Could you please tell me how you derived this?

Comment: Basically, anything involving multiples of any integer should most of the time be related with modulos, or floor, ceiling and fractional functions, and these should do the trick. Here, the first term is merely the first value of the sequence, and the second term calculates the total sum per cycle (here it would be $3+3+5 = 11$), and the final one calculates the remainder after taking out all possible $3$'s. In other words, it can be generalised.

Comment: Ohhhh thank you so much! Could you please direct me to a link where it is used or explained in depth? What is this called in Mathematics?

Comment: I don't think there are any websites that explain this in depth (I think these types of equations are just generalised under sequences). I'll try explain it in depth here. First of all, we need the first term in the sequence at the front (since every term in the sequence after that is just a certain difference from the first term). The second term here counts the amount of multiples of 3 that are in $n$. This is because the pattern of adding (+3,+3,+5) can be seen in the sequence to repeat forever, and so every cycle of 3 terms adds +11. In other words, we can say that $a_{3n+1} = 2+11n$.

Comment: Hmm and how do we reach to the conclusion from a_3n+1 = 2 +11n?

Comment: We can see that your sequence (P.S. i dont think it follows the rule of +5 for every multiple of 4, as it adds on the 4th, 7th and 10th term), adds by +3, +3, +5 (the differences between consecutive terms).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150519/discussion-between-aaa-lol-dude-and-andy2000).